# enum from key of objects in array typescript

Tags: typescript

Using `const storage : Readonly<{id: string}[]>`, how to type some `string` to be within one of the static `id` in `storage`? The array will not change during runtime and is hardcoded in.

I tried `(typeof storage)[number]['id']` but that's just `string`. Also tried `satisfies Readonly<{id:string}[]>`.

```js
interface HasID {
  id: string
  info?: any
}
const storage : Readonly<HasID[]> = [
 { id: 'foo' },
 { id: 'bar', info: ['baz'] }
]
const storage2 = [
  { id: 'foo' },
  { id: 'bar', info: ['baz'] }
] satisfies Readonly<HasID[]>

let str // looking to type this to be "foo" | "bar"

type StorageID = (typeof storage)[number]['id'] // string
type StorageID2 = (typeof storage2)[number]['id'] // string
```

Comment: switching `interface` for `type` also doesm't type narrow.

Comment: Ah, I just added `as const` without even realizing it did it, which is what you need. As shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WY5MgW).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yep i think it fully addresses the question. thank you! I saw it before but haven't used it in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when people write [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) or [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) they are just trying to initialize some mutable variable and expect the contents to change. So TypeScript infers these rather widely.  So even with [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator), you'll get something wider than you want:

```
const storage = [
  { id: 'foo' },
  { id: 'bar', info: ['baz'] }
] satisfies Readonly<HasID[]>;
/*
const storage: ({
    id: string;
    info?: undefined;
} | {
    id: string;
    info: string[];
})[]
*/
```

The specific [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `id` properties are lost.

---

In cases where you don't plan to mutate the contents of a literal object or array, **you can use [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)** to ask TypeScript to infer a much more specific type:

```
const storage = [
  { id: 'foo' },
  { id: 'bar', info: ['baz'] }
] as const satisfies Readonly<HasID[]>
/* 
const storage: readonly [{
    readonly id: "foo";
}, {
    readonly id: "bar";
    readonly info: readonly ["baz"];
}]
*/
```

That type keeps track of the literal types of the `id` property (as well as the order of the array elements).  And now your approach of using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) will work as desired:

```
type StorageID = (typeof storage)[number]['id']
//   ^? type StorageID = "foo" | "bar"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJwM4EkAiyDeAsAFDLLAAmAXMhmFKAOYlmgwD2A-DXCAJ4kAviRIg4AWwgYADohQB5BowItkCdiDq0w7KHEYoAvMgDaqsvnLVkAcg7sbyQQBpzBKzRsAjOFBvPyEA4aE284AC8bAF0nVRiMODBgDBhgKWQAJQg4Cg0AGz4AHnRsHBMogD4AbhFSZAB6ACpVdU0wbV19CBoACiI6slZrOgYQRhqBwbYuGgBXEAoIVJAICgmyQWQAHxVJoZoRpnXB1iD2A-omcuPBAEpy1Ub6oVqSVq06ToNkYzM6y0onnsjhcqgB1jCfgC0xCYUiMWExBimDUGg+iWSqXSWRy+SKJVw5QqJCayDeaPanz0BhoUGyuRABVM-ROdNxjL4HmQACJ7NyJi5dqz6XiudyfFB+W42QymTDkDLRSZxRFuVEBVESE9amA+NIUABlHTUiC4H7IHq6-XsGAdE33ECzcReaBRUKUaIk+qDAB6nGQVsNxq6ZuMvPY7G52x5Eu5QA)